# Very slow postgres ORDER BY performance despite indices

Tags: postgresql

Following tables:

- Collections (around 100 records)
- Events (related to collections, around 6000 per collection)
- Sales (related to events, in total around 2m records)

I need to get all sales for a certain collection, sorted by either sales.timestamp DESC (datetime field) or sales.id DESC (since id is already in insertion order) but to filter by collection_id I need to join the events table in first, then filter by e.collection_id.

To help with this I created a separate index on timestamp: `idx_sales_timestamp_desc (timestamp DESC NULLS LAST)`, alongside the usual pkey index on sales.id

```
EXPLAIN (analyze,buffers) SELECT * from sales s 
LEFT JOIN events e ON s.sales_event = e.sales_event
WHERE e.collection_id = 9
ORDER BY s.id DESC -- identical results with s.timestamp
LIMIT 10;
```

Without the ORDER:

```
Limit  (cost=0.85..196.61 rows=10 width=619) (actual time=0.069..2.416 rows=10 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=172 read=3
  I/O Timings: read=1.810
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..122231.34 rows=6244 width=619) (actual time=0.068..2.413 rows=10 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=172 read=3
        I/O Timings: read=1.810
        ->  Index Scan using idx_events_collection_id on events e  (cost=0.43..32359.71 rows=9551 width=206) (actual time=0.027..0.074 rows=47 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (collection_id = 9)
              Buffers: shared hit=24
        ->  Index Scan using idx_sales_sales_event on sales s  (cost=0.42..9.39 rows=2 width=413) (actual time=0.049..0.049 rows=0 loops=47)
              Index Cond: (sales_event = e.sales_event)
              Buffers: shared hit=148 read=3
              I/O Timings: read=1.810
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=20
Planning Time: 0.418 ms
Execution Time: 2.444 ms
```

With the order:

```
Limit  (cost=1001.00..3353.78 rows=10 width=619) (actual time=1084.650..2353.191 rows=10 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=81908 read=6967 dirtied=1930
  I/O Timings: read=3732.771
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1001.00..1470076.56 rows=6244 width=619) (actual time=1084.649..2352.683 rows=10 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=81908 read=6967 dirtied=1930
        I/O Timings: read=3732.771
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.98..1468355.82 rows=2602 width=619) (actual time=622.297..1768.414 rows=6 loops=3)
              Buffers: shared hit=81908 read=6967 dirtied=1930
              I/O Timings: read=3732.771
              ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using sales_pkey on sales s  (cost=0.42..58907.93 rows=303693 width=413) (actual time=0.237..301.251 rows=6008 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=9958 read=1094 dirtied=1479
                    I/O Timings: read=513.609
              ->  Index Scan using events_pkey on events e  (cost=0.55..4.64 rows=1 width=206) (actual time=0.243..0.243 rows=0 loops=18024)
                    Index Cond: (sales_event = s.sales_event)
                    Filter: (collection_id = 9)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                    Buffers: shared hit=71950 read=5873 dirtied=451
                    I/O Timings: read=3219.161
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=20
Planning Time: 0.268 ms
Execution Time: 2354.905 ms
```

sales DDL:

```
-- Table Definition ----------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE sales (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    transaction text,
    sales_event text,
    price bigint,
    name text,
    timestamp timestamp with time zone,
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sales_pkey ON sales(id int8_ops);
CREATE INDEX idx_sales_sales_event ON sales(sales_event text_ops);
CREATE INDEX idx_sales_timestamp_desc ON sales(timestamp timestamptz_ops DESC);
```

Events DDL:

```
-- Table Definition ----------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE events (
    created_at timestamp with time zone,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    sales_event text PRIMARY KEY,
    collection_id bigint REFERENCES collections(id) REFERENCES collections(id),
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX events_pkey ON events(sales_event text_ops);
```

Without the ORDER BY, I'm at around 500ms. With the ORDER BY, it easily ends up in the 2s-3m or longer category, depending on DB load, despite all indices being used according to the explain.

The default order when omitting `ORDER BY` altogether is not the one I want. I kept `ANALYZE` up to date as well.

How do I solve this in a good way?

Comment: The execution plans (slow **and** fast) generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)` would be more helpful

Comment: Why does one plan have a LIMIT?

Comment: please post the DDL and the INDEX for the tables sales and events. since you filtre on events (e.collection_id = 9) and you order on sales (id), Postgres need to compute all the join, filter it and the order it. you need also statistic uptodate

Comment: Can you invert the order of the tables in the FROM clause : `SELECT * from events e RIGHT JOIN sales s ON s.sales_event = e.sales_event ...` and share the `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` result ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll be attaching the requested data asap

Comment: DDL, explain (analyze, buffers) has been added